# SQL Server create an ID for each distinct value in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table [DWH].[Division] which looks like this:

```
| Company ID | Division Code | Division Key |
|------------|---------------|--------------|
| 01         | PROD          | 1            |
| 02         | PROD          | 2            |
| 01         | MAN           | 3            |
| 04         | MAN           | 4            |
| 03         | PROD          | 5            |
```

I am trying to add a new column called [Global Division Code], so that whenever a row with an existsting [Division Code] is inserted, it will the corresponding integer value from [Global Division Code] and when a row with a new [Division Code] is inserted, the next highest integer value from [Global Division Code] will be used. The existing [Division Key] column uses INT IDENTITY(1,1). Values are only inserted into this table when the combination of [Company ID] and [Division Code] does not yes exist in the table.

The result would look like this:

```
| Company ID | Division Code | Division Key | Global Division Key |
|------------|---------------|--------------|---------------------|
| 01         | PROD          | 1            | 1                   |
| 02         | PROD          | 2            | 1                   |
| 01         | MAN           | 3            | 2                   |
| 04         | MAN           | 4            | 2                   |
| 03         | PROD          | 5            | 1                   |
```

When I add a new row with [Division Code] 'FIN' the result would be:

```
| Company ID | Division Code | Division Key | Global Division Key |
|------------|---------------|--------------|---------------------|
| 01         | PROD          | 1            | 1                   |
| 02         | PROD          | 2            | 1                   |
| 01         | MAN           | 3            | 2                   |
| 04         | MAN           | 4            | 2                   |
| 03         | PROD          | 5            | 1                   |
| 01         | FIN           | 6            | 3                   |
```

The data for this table is inserted from a staging-table via a MERGE-statement.

I have tried to use a sequence for this, so that whenever the merge insertes new data it will check if there is already a global division key for the row's division code. If there is, it was supposed to use that code, if not, grab the next value from the sequence. However, SQL Server will not let me use the NEXT VALUE function in a subquery. There has to be a better solution out there than using a cursor to post-process the [DWH].[Division] table row by row.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do what you want with a trigger.  But that is not a good idea.

You have a failure in your data model.  You should have a *separate* table for the global divisions with one row per global division code and key.  The key can be assigned as an `identity` column.

You can "hide" the underlying structure of the data by using indexed views, if you like.  That is, you can have a view where the data looks like the results you want.  Under the hood, though, there are two tables.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I would like to avoid having a snowflake-schema and prefer to keep the [Global Division Key] column in the [Division] table. Especially since there are no 'real' global dimensions. The column should only serve as a means of sorting  [Division Code] by an integer in a BI-Environment. I may end up having the snowflake anyway and just joining the two tables in a view later on. Thanks again!

Comment: @Stephan . . . You can also calculate the id on the fly, but if it is permanently stored, it is an entity and worthy of its own table.   You don't have to expose it to users as a separate table, however.